# How to pass down data from Stateful classes to another Stateful class that exists in another file?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm having trouble passing the data that's been filled in a textformfields and selected in a dropdown menu.

I'm trying to use the Map function to pass down String values so that I can also pass down all types of values in the future (ex. int, bool, double etc.), however it's not working so I need someone to check it out.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workoutapp/auth/auth.dart';
import 'package:workoutapp/auth/root_page.dart';
import 'package:workoutapp/inheritedWigets/auth_provider.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(
    WorkoutManager(),
  );
}

class WorkoutManager extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AuthProvider(
      auth: Auth(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Workout Manager',
        home: RootPage(),
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.indigo,
          primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
          accentColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
          hintColor: Colors.indigo,
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

HomePage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workoutapp/inheritedWigets/auth_provider.dart';

import './profile_account_page.dart';
import './routines_create_page.dart';

import '../objects/Routines/routines_manager.dart';

import '../tools/custom_drawer.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;
  final List<Map<String, String>> routines;

  HomePage({Key key, this.onSignedOut, this.routines}) : super(key: key);

  void _signedOut(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      var auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
      await auth.signOut();
      onSignedOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Workout Manager', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        centerTitle: false,
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Logout'),
            onPressed: () {
              return _signedOut(context);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
            tooltip: 'Profile Account',
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              return Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return ProfileAccountPage();
              }));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return RoutinesPageCreate();
          }));
        },
      ),
      body: RoutinesManager(),
      drawer: CustomDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

RoutineManager

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workoutapp/objects/routines/routines.dart';

class RoutinesManager extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, String> startingRoutine;

  RoutinesManager({this.startingRoutine});

  @override
  _RoutinesManagerState createState() => _RoutinesManagerState();
}

class _RoutinesManagerState extends State<RoutinesManager> {
  List<Map<String, String>> _routines = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.startingRoutine != null) {
      _routines.add(widget.startingRoutine);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Routines(_routines),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

RoutinesCreatePage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workoutapp/pages/home_page.dart';

class RoutinesPageCreate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RoutinesPageCreateState createState() => _RoutinesPageCreateState();
}

class _RoutinesPageCreateState extends State<RoutinesPageCreate> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<Map<String, String>> _routines = [];

  String _routineName, _routineDescription;

  var _routineNameController = TextEditingController();
  var _routineDescriptionController = TextEditingController();

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropdownListBodyPartMenuItem = [];
  List<String> _dropdownListBodyPart = [
    'Chest',
    'Back',
    'Leg',
    'Shoulder',
    'Abs',
  ];
  String _selectedBodyPart;

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropdownListDayOfWeekMenuItem = [];
  List<String> _dropdownListDayOfWeek = [
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
    'Sunday',
  ];
  String _selectedDayOfWeek;

  void loadBodyPartData() {
    _dropdownListBodyPartMenuItem = [];
    _dropdownListBodyPartMenuItem = _dropdownListBodyPart.map((val) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        child: Text(val),
        value: val,
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  void loadDayOfWeekData() {
    _dropdownListDayOfWeekMenuItem = [];
    _dropdownListDayOfWeekMenuItem = _dropdownListDayOfWeek.map((val) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        child: Text(val),
        value: val,
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  final _scaffoldState = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void _showSnakBarReset() {
    _scaffoldState.currentState.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        content: Text('Showing SnackBar TEST'),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showSnakBarCreateWorkoutRoutine() {
    _scaffoldState.currentState.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        content: Text('Workout Routine has been created'),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _addRoutine(Map<String, String> routine) {
    setState(() {
      _routines.add(routine);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loadBodyPartData();
    loadDayOfWeekData();
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldState,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Create Routines'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: ListView(children: buildInputs() + buildCreateButtons()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> buildInputs() {
    TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title;
    return [
      TextFormField(
          controller: _routineNameController,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.length > 20) {
              return 'Not a valid Routine Name';
            }
          },
          onSaved: (value) {
            return _routineName = value;
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelStyle: textStyle,
              labelText: 'Routine Name',
              hintText: 'Enter the Routine Name for this day',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              ))),
      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
      TextFormField(
          controller: _routineDescriptionController,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.length > 50) {
              return 'Invalid: The Description must be 50 characters or less.';
            }
          },
          onSaved: (value) {
            return _routineDescription = value;
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelStyle: textStyle,
              labelText: 'Description',
              hintText: 'Enter the description of the Routine.',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              ))),
      Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton(
                  value: _selectedBodyPart,
                  items: _dropdownListBodyPartMenuItem,
                  hint: Text('Select Body Part', style: textStyle),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedBodyPart = value;
                    });
                  })),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
          ),
          DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton(
              value: _selectedDayOfWeek,
              items: _dropdownListDayOfWeekMenuItem,
              hint: Text('Select Day of Week', style: textStyle),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedDayOfWeek = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> buildCreateButtons() {
    return [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                  textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  child: Text('Create Workout Routine'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      _showSnakBarCreateWorkoutRoutine();
                      formKey.currentState.save();
                      _addRoutine({
                        'routineName': 'Chest Workout',
                        'description': 'Heavy',
                        'bodyPart': 'Chest',
                        'week': 'Monday',
                      });
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return HomePage();
                      }));
                    } else {
                      return null;
                    }
                  }),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                child: Text('Reset'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _showSnakBarReset();
                    formKey.currentState.reset();
                    _selectedBodyPart = null;
                    _selectedDayOfWeek = null;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

Routines

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workoutapp/objects/routines/routines_detail.dart';

class Routines extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, String>> routines;

  Routines(this.routines);

  Widget _buildRoutinesItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title;
    return Expanded(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Text(routines[index]['routineName'], style: textStyle)),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Text(routines[index]['description'], style: textStyle)),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Text(routines[index]['bodyPart'], style: textStyle)),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Text(routines[index]['week'], style: textStyle)),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: ButtonBar(
                alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Details'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      return Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return RoutinesDetail(
                            routines[index]['routineName'],
                            routines[index]['description'],
                            routines[index]['bodyPart'],
                            routines[index]['week']);
                      }));
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRoutinesList(context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title;
    Widget routinesCards = Container(
      child: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("No routines found, please add some.", style: textStyle),
        ),
      ),
    );
    if (routines.length > 0 || routines.length <= 7) {
      ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: _buildRoutinesItem,
        itemCount: routines.length,
      );
    }
    return routinesCards;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildRoutinesList(context);
  }
}
```

RoutineDetailPage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RoutinesDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  final String routineName, description, bodyPart, week;

  RoutinesDetail(this.routineName, this.description, this.bodyPart, this.week);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(routineName),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Text(routineName, style: textStyle)),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Text(description, style: textStyle)),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Text(bodyPart, style: textStyle)),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Text(week, style: textStyle)),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Delete'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to separate the code into multiple files as much as possible, so it's more "readable" and make it easy for myself to make changes to the code  whenever I have to in the future.
The problem is, it's quite spit up, I don't understand how to use the data and pass it down or up to the pages or widgets as there are multiple stateful and stateless widgets that are suppose to work together to make this app possible.

You'll notice on the HomePage file (StatelessWidget), I'm trying to show the Scaffold body argument with the RoutinesManager StatefulWidget, which is in a different file. At the same time in the HomePage file, I have a Scaffold floatingActionButton argument that will take you to the RoutinesCreatePage StatefulWidget to create a List of Cards (StatelessWidget) using the ListView.builder(). However, no Card gets created under the HomePage after the "Create Workout Routine" RaisedButton gets pressed in the RoutinesCreatePage and no data gets passed.

Can someone please help me out here as I am totally clueless. Also, I'm fairly a beginner regarding flutter/dart so a solution with a relatively easy to understand explanation would be very helpful.

Note: I do have other files that contribute to this app, however I don't think they're part of the problem so I left them out intentionally.

If more information is needed, please do let me know.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you misunderstand what state in Flutter is. To explain in short, state is the internal status/data/... that belongs that that specific widget. `StatefulWidget` has state to determine if UI should be re-rendered on its own state change. External widgets never know about other widgets' states.

So it means, any state change happening inside `RoutinesCreatePage` widget, only that `RoutinesCreatePage` knows and reacts. Unless, you inform other widgets to know something has changed.

Alright, so talking about navigation, it works like a stack structure. `HomePage` trigger a push to `RoutinesCreatePage`, then to return, you need to `pop`, not another `push`.

Here a quick fix for your code, you can try.

**HomePage**

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {
        handleNewRoutine();  <---  this is to handle navigation and retrieve returning data from pop
    },  
),

Future handleNewRoutine() async {

    var newRoutine = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RoutinesPageCreate());
    )

    if (newRoutine == null) {
        // nothing returns from RoutinesPageCreate widget
        // so do nothing then
    } else {
        // add to routine list 
        // and trigger list re-rendering
        setState(() {
            this.routines.add(newRoutine); 
        });
    }
}
```

**RoutinesCreatePage**: when clicking submit button, just populate all data from input fields, make object model and pop to return data to where this widget was pushed.

```
onPressed: () {
    var newRoutine = .... // populate from UI to create new Routine model object.
    Navigator.pop(context, newRoutine);
}
```

Also, take time to read the navigation guide from official Flutter documentation. It is very detailed on this part. https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

Some additional comments to your code:

- in `RoutinesCreatePage` you don't need to know application level state, I mean `_routines` variable is unnecessary. You only need one object to store new routine to pop back to `HomePage`.
- in `Routines`, this method `Widget _buildRoutinesList(context)` having unused `ListView` creation.

  `if (routines.length > 0 || routines.length <= 7) {
        ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: _buildRoutinesItem,
          itemCount: routines.length,
        );
      }`

Comment: Hi @pete!!!

Thank you soo much for providing answers to my question and my apologies for the lack of knowledge regarding the navigation in Flutter. I totally understand what you mean and the doc does clarify what you're stating.

I'm really sorry to ask, however may I kindly ask, under the submit button, how you would create new Routine model objects in this case??? Do I create a separate class that can store data from each text fields and dropdown lists? The more example the better.... my sincerest apologies.

Comment: @JohnT. Yes, just a class with properties. `Routine({this.name, this.bodyPart, this.description, this.week})`  so you don't have to store with something complicated like what you did `Map<String, String>`.